# Who was this friend of Bill's?

Tags: character-identification, gravity-falls

In a few scenes of the *Weirdmageddon* arc, we see this guy:

[image: Bowler hat guy 1]

[image: Bowler hat guy 2]

Bill names all his friends except for him and he's missing from many important scenes.

So who is he? And why was he seemingly forgotten or partially cut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

His name was revealed (in a deleted scene) to be "[*Lava Lamp Guy*](https://gravityfalls.fandom.com/wiki/Lava_Lamp_Guy)".

And you're not wrong, mention of him was cut from the episode.